# No governance within substrate-parachain-template

Tags: runtime-upgrade, substrate-parachain-template

Does anyone know why the template provided in [this](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) repo doesn't include any governance? I noticed that the `Cumulus` repo does include a [sudo](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L489).

I run a parachain using this template and was unable to perform an upgrade due to the lack of governance. As a result, I had to instantiate a new parachain from scratch, this time including the sudo pallet. Actually, I still have an [unresolved](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/upgrade-parachain-without-sudo) question about performing the upgrade from the relay chain as a workaround.

What's the rationale behind excluding any form of governance from this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this 2 weeks ago on GitHub: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/2748.

However, the CI has not synchronized the changes between these repositories for 3 weeks. It would be advisable to request an update at that mirrored repository.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [extended-parachain-template](https://github.com/paritytech/extended-parachain-template/tree/main) supported by Parity. A ready-for-hacking parachain template, pre-configured a governance system (Collective & Motion pallets) among other pallets.