# Collator throwing "set_validation_data inherent needs to be present in every block!" error every so often

Tags: rococo, parachain-collator

I'm running 2 collators for a rococo parachain, and every so often they throw the following error:

```
2024-01-26 15:37:24 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2024-01-26 15:37:24 [Parachain] ❗️ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x4f0c7e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xc0d5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha38e6eecb0b0460a
    2: 0x138930 - <unknown>!cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::<impl cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Pallet<T>>::maybe_drop_included_ancestors::haffe4e2473a55f94
    3: 0x2ff8ab - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::h96eabf484a536fae
    4: 0x38c027 - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Call<T> as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::{{closure}}::h072e3d5063d8ecd6
    5: 0x39c4ab - <unknown>!environmental::local_key::LocalKey<T>::with::hdfe7ff7a67cc35fb
    6: 0x433bd - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h50ba6ab435d9ce83
    7: 0x41555 - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as sp_runtime::traits::Dispatchable>::dispatch::h0d7888a94bcec6cb
    8: 0x38cd52 - <unknown>!<sp_runtime::generic::checked_extrinsic::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId,Call,Extra> as sp_runtime::traits::Applyable>::apply::h7ff1a26f626b4efc
    9: 0x34bc4f - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::apply_extrinsic::h1fa340d793d8060b
   10: 0x3c8864 - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic. Dropping.    
2024-01-26 15:37:24 [Parachain] panicked at 'set_validation_data inherent needs to be present in every block!', /home/sebastian/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/7c9fd83/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:268:18    
2024-01-26 15:37:24 [Parachain] err=Error { inner: Proposing

Caused by:
    0: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
       WASM backtrace:
       error while executing at wasm backtrace:
           0: 0x4f0c7e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
           1: 0xc0d5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha38e6eecb0b0460a
           2: 0xc083 - <unknown>!core::option::expect_failed::hea4dd73f37ab58ac
           3: 0x133269 - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<<<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::Block as sp_runtime::traits::HeaderProvider>::HeaderT as sp_runtime::traits::Header>::Number>>::on_finalize::hb7107cdcee56d33b
           4: 0x34c120 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::idle_and_finalize_hook::hc83c4073d3f381c9
           5: 0x34c23e - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::finalize_block::ha23dd198865f8803
           6: 0x3c891b - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_finalize_block
    1: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
       WASM backtrace:
       error while executing at wasm backtrace:
           0: 0x4f0c7e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
           1: 0xc0d5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha38e6eecb0b0460a
           2: 0xc083 - <unknown>!core::option::expect_failed::hea4dd73f37ab58ac
           3: 0x133269 - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<<<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::Block as sp_runtime::traits::HeaderProvider>::HeaderT as sp_runtime::traits::Header>::Number>>::on_finalize::hb7107cdcee56d33b
           4: 0x34c120 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::idle_and_finalize_hook::hc83c4073d3f381c9
           5: 0x34c23e - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::finalize_block::ha23dd198865f8803
           6: 0x3c891b - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_finalize_block }
```

The collators still produce blocks, but because of this issue, every so often they skip producing blocks.

Does anyone know what might be the cause?

I've seen this post: [Failure on HRMP channel creation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/failure-on-hrmp-channel-creation), but the cause mentioned on the issue does not apply on my case as the parachain ids do match.

The collators are running `polkadot 1.3.0`.